# Wake on Radio in Telit's LE70-868

Tags: microcontroller, rf, wireless, uart, hardware

Hi I'm designing one application which have rf communication over the 868 Mhz.
i'm using Telit's LE70-868 Module it support the wake on radio feature. but i have configure as per its datasheet but it not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selected to wake up mode 
register from S240 
S240=1 = hardware sleep mode
S240=2 = software sleep modesoftware sleep mode input send-> ATP